# Need to know if mysql query can get this type of result

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a Table structure like below

```
+--------+---------+
| cat_id | user_id |
+--------+---------+
|     10 |       1 |
|     10 |       2 |
|     11 |       3 |
|     11 |       4 |
+--------+---------+
```

I'm trying to get the result like below

```
Array
(
    [cat_id] => 10,
    Array
    (
        [user_id] => 1,
        [user_id] => 2
    )
)

Array
(
    [cat_id] => 11,
    Array
    (
        [user_id] => 3,
        [user_id] => 4
    )
)
```

I tried using group it didn't work, If i try with sub query i get error message "Subquery returns more than 1 row."

Is it possible to achieve this kind of result using mysql query?

Comment: How many users there can be by `cat_id`? Also, how are you building that array? What language?

Answer (score 1):

MYSQL not providing customization in result set. you will be required to prepare required array using PHP once you get the required result set from mysql.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot achieve what you want using pure mysql ..

You need some server side language to make the required customization.

In php you can do it like

```
$req_array     = array();
$con           = mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
$result        = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `table`");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{
    $req_array[$row['cat_id']][] = $row['user_id'];
}
```

Now change this array as you want

```
$result_array  = array();
foreach($req_array as $key=>$value)
{
  $result_array[]  = array('cat_id'=>$key,'users'=>$value)
}
print_r($result_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

**No,** MySQL api funcions provide a result set of your records. They cannot customize to your requirements. You have to create your own functions to develop that format.

Start by getting unique category id and they go through them in a loop to get there remaining details.

```
$mainArray = []; //Create a array to store the records
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT DISTINCT('cat_id') as catid FROM `yourtable`");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {       

    //Now another query to fetch the users
    $res = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `yourtable` WHERE cat_id='$row[0]'");

    $users = array(); //array to store users
    while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
         $users[] = $r['user_id'];
    }

    // Now add to your main array
    $mainArray[] = array('cat_id' => $row['catid'], "users" => $users);
}
var_dump($mainArray);
```

Comment: That would really suck performance-wise.  Do the select cat_id, user_id order by cat_id query once then skip through the result set in one pass checking to see when your cat_id changes or otherwise looking up an existing cat_id (I don't know that language so can't be more specific). @Let's Code has it right.

Comment: @LoztInSpace, I agree. I was giving an idea.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it using PHP, but i wanted to know if its possible using pure mysql query. Thanks for all your suggestions. With the help of PHP while loop and array i achieved the below result.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [catid] => 10
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [user_id] => 1
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [user_id] => 2
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [catid] => 11
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [user_id] => 3
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [user_id] => 4
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: what is php you are using ?

Answer (score 0):

To alleviate some pain and get all `user_id` values grouped by `cat_id` in one roundtrip to MySql you can utilize `GROUP_CONCAT()`. Your query will look like

```sql
SELECT cat_id, GROUP_CONCAT(user_id) user_id 
  FROM table1 GROUP BY cat_id
```

Output:

```
| CAT_ID | USER_ID |
--------------------
|     10 |     1,2 |
|     11 |     3,4 |
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2a277/1)**

Then iterate trough the resultset and use `explode()` to build your new array the way you want it.